# How to avoid capturing groups if the captured match is empty?

Tags: javascript, regex

I would like to prepend the word `"custom"` to a list of host-names whose subdomains can be separated by some separator.

Examples:

```
news.google.com   -> custom.news.google.com
news/google/com   -> custom.news.google.com

dev.maps.yahoo.fr -> custom.dev.maps.yahoo.fr
dev/maps/yahoo/fr -> custom/dev/maps/yahoo/fr
```

These strings appear inside a document with more content, so I am trying to solve this problem using regular expressions and JavaScript's string `replace` function.

The list of hostnames and separators is predefined and known in advance. For the sake of this example, I only showed 2 hostnames (`news.google.com` and `dev.maps.yahoo.com`) and 2 separators (`.` and `/`), but there are more.

The separator within a single string will always be the same, i.e. there won't be cases like `dev/maps.yahoo/fr`.

I want to be consistent and use the correct separator when prepending `"custom"`.

I built this long regular expression:

```js
const myRegex = /news\.google\.com|news\/google\/com|dev\.maps\.yahoo\.fr|dev\/maps\/yahoo\/fr/
```

(For readability purposes, this is the expression:

`/news\.google\.com/`
OR
`/news\/google\/com/`
OR
`/dev\.maps\.yahoo\.fr/`
OR
`/dev\/maps\/yahoo\/fr/`
)

(Note: It is important to emphasize that the list of hostnames is predefined and well known in advance, that's why I am 'hardcoding' the hostnames and not using tokens such as `\w+` or `\S+`. For example, I might want to replace `news.google.com`, but leave `news2.google.com` intact).

However, I am not sure how to capture the separator (whether `.`, `/`, or any other separator). I tried using capture groups like this:

```js
const myRegex = /news(\.)google\.com|news(\/)google\/com|dev(\.)maps\.yahoo\.fr|dev(\/)maps\/yahoo\/fr/
```

However, by doing this, I am creating 4 capture groups, and there's only one separator (and this is just a simple example). 3 of the capture groups will be empty, and one of them will contain the separator. How can I know which capture group is it?

Ideally, I would like something like this:

```js
const myString = 'I navigated to news.google.com'; // For example
const myCustomString = myString.replace(
  myRegex,
  (match, <SEPARATOR_WRONG>) => `custom${SEPARATOR_WRONG}${match}`,
);

console.log(myCustomString); 
// will log 'I navigated to custom.news.google.com'
```

Is there a way to skip captured groups if they are empty?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `\1` to refer to the separator captured in the first `(\.|\/)` group so we don't have to keep writing it over and over.

```js
const text = `I navigated to news.google.com
I navigated to news/google/com
I navigated to dev.maps.yahoo.fr
I navigated to dev/maps/yahoo/fr`;

const re = /\w+(\.|\/)(\w+\1)?(google|yahoo)\1\w+/g;
console.log(text.replace(re, (url, separator) => `custom${separator}${url}`));
```

Here's an alternate solution given the new requirement described in the comments:

```js
const text = `I navigated to news.google.com
I navigated to news/google/com
I navigated to dev.maps.yahoo.fr
I navigated to dev/maps/yahoo/fr`;

const re = /(news|dev)(\.|\/)(google|maps)\2(com|yahoo)(\2fr)?/g;

console.log(text.replace(re, (url, prefix, separator) => `custom${separator}${url}`));
```

Yet another alternate solution:

```js
const text = `I navigated to news.google.com
I navigated to news/google/com
I navigated to dev.maps.yahoo.fr
I navigated to dev/maps/yahoo/fr`;

const re = /news(\.)google\.com|news(\/)google\/com|dev(\.)maps\.yahoo\.fr|dev(\/)maps\/yahoo\/fr/g;

console.log(text.replace(re, url => 'custom' + url.match(/\.|\//)[0] + url));
```

Comment: I hadn't thought of using `\1` to backreference the capture groups, thanks for that. However, I just edited the question to emphasize that the list of hostnames is well known in advance, and we can't use patterns such as `\w+` to match the strings.

Comment: I updated the answer with a solution fitting that requirement.

Comment: I think this won't work because you're looking for patterns in the host names, when there aren't. Suppose there is a new hostname: 'sub1.sub2.sub3.sub4.sub5', which is not `yahoo` or `google`, does not end on `com` or on `fr`. As I said, the host names in the question are just examples.

Comment: I added a third answer using your regex.

Comment: I like the third answer, I think it is the correct one...I didn't find any way to "skip" captured groups.

Answer (score 1):

solution that I believe is acceptable to you is to add separator finding logic among the capture groups in the callback

```
const myCustomString = myString.replace(
  myRegex,
  (match, ...rest) => {
     const sep = rest.slice(0, -2) // last two args are index and full match
      .find(sep => !!sep) // first truthy capture group contains a separator
      return `custom${sep}${match}`},
);
```

Comment: 2nd part of this post is still a working answer, considering edits done 1 min ago

Comment: Hi Andrei, no, there is no common pattern for the hostnames, I just edited the question to clarify that

Comment: i deleted the 1st part so you would see the working part better

Comment: This answer works, but do you know if there's a more efficient way to it? Iterating through all the capturing groups just to find the single separator seems inefficient. As I mentioned, in the question's example there are only four capturing groups, but there could be way more.

Comment: Sorry, there are only two capturing groups in the question's example, but there could be more.

Comment: the answer works for any number of groups, but there is no way of uniting different pieces of regex into one capture group. So I believe this solution is the only option